# Get Latest Date for Device In One Table and Pull Related Field From Second Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have "table1"...

```
╔══════════╤═════════════════════════╤══════════╤══════════╗
║ EventID  │ UpdateTime              │ User     │ DeviceID ║
╠══════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╣
║ 1        │ 2018-03-27 17:36:34.080 │ Sally    │ 129      ║
╟──────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────╢
║ 2        │ 2018-03-27 17:47:44.057 │ Jack     │ 563      ║
╟──────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────╢
║ 3        │ 2018-03-29 02:14:01.203 │ Bob      │ 789      ║
╟──────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────╢
║ 4        │ 2018-03-27 17:23:11.350 │ Cathy    │ 352      ║
╟──────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────╢
║ 5        │ 2018-03-27 17:35:31.470 │ John     │ 352      ║
╟──────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────╢
║ 6        │ 2018-03-27 17:36:34.080 │ Margaret │ 2376     ║
╚══════════╧═════════════════════════╧══════════╧══════════╝
```

...and "table2"...

```
╔══════════╤═════════════╤════════╗
║ ID       │ DeviceName  │ Active ║
╠══════════╪═════════════╪════════╣
║ 129      │ DeviceA     │ False  ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼────────╢
║ 563      │ DeviceB     │ True   ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼────────╢
║ 789      │ DeviceC     │ True   ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼────────╢
║ 352      │ DeviceD     │ True   ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼────────╢
║ 2376     │ DeviceE     │ False  ║
╚══════════╧═════════════╧════════╝
```

I want to end up with this:

```
╔═════════════╤═════════════════════════╤══════╗
║ DeviceName  │ LatestUpdateTime        │ User ║
╠═════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════╣
║ DeviceB     │ 2018-03-27 17:47:44.057 │ Jack ║
╟─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ DeviceC     │ 2018-03-29 02:14:01.203 │ Bob  ║
╟─────────────┼─────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ DeviceD     │ 2018-03-27 17:35:31.470 │ John ║
╚═════════════╧═════════════════════════╧══════╝
```

I have already:

```
SELECT t2.DeviceName, t1.UpdateTime, t1.User
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(UpdateTime) AS 'LatestUpdateTime', DeviceID
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY DeviceID
    ) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.DeviceID
WHERE t2.Active = 'True'
ORDER BY t2.DeviceName
```

Which gets me "DeviceName" and "LatestUpdateTime" as I want but I cannot figure out how to get "User" as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Had a tough time searching for this and also deciding on title here.  If you have any better ideas, I am interested in that as well.

Comment: UpdateTime and DeviceID are not part of table2, the query must be in error.

Comment: @MikeL.-I've recreated your tables and provided a demo for you to try out.

Comment: How do you want to handle breaking ties?

Comment: Just my two cents, if you decide to break ties I'd recommend using `t1.EventID DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[DEMO]](https://www.rextester.com/FXQPTO84463)

I would use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.DeviceName, 
        t1.UpdateTime,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.DeviceID ORDER BY t1.UpdateTime DESC) RowNum, 
        t1.[User]
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.DeviceID = t2.ID
    WHERE t2.Active = 'True')

SELECT DeviceName, UpdateTime LatestUpdateTime, [User] 
FROM cte
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY DeviceName
```

[image]

---

I am ordering the `t1.UpdateTime DESC` and assigning a row number to it.

Each time a duplicate `t1.DeviceID` is found, a incremental number is assigned, thus is why I am choosing to find `RowNum = 1` (meaning, give me the latest update time).

One of the problems you might be facing as well is the usage of the [Reserved Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) `User`. Notice how I wrapped it in square brackets `[User]`.

---

If you've got a tie, I'd recommend using `t1.EventID DESC`.

So you'd change the ordering on `RowNum` to be:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.DeviceID ORDER BY t1.UpdateTime DESC, t1.EventID DESC)
```

Comment: @kc2018 Thanks! I figure it's best to give the OP enough information to solve the specific issue but try to teach along the way too. I think if they've been given a few resources, they will be able to help themselves if the query changes at a later time. Kudos to _@Habo_ for bringing up the "ties". Adjusted my answer to account for that.

Comment: Perfect @Brien.  Also appreciated the detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.DeviceName, t1.UpdateTime as LatestUpdateTime, t1.User1 
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY DEVICEID ORDER BY updatetime DESC) as rn FROM table1) t1
ON t1.deviceID = t2.ID AND t1.rn = 1
WHERE t2.Active = 'True'
ORDER BY t2.DeviceName
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=862d0a626d3241d31db265a9d38ba121)